# How do I know if it's safe to connect the common grounds of the input signals of two garage door openers?

Tags: home-automation, home-installation

I have two [Hormann ProMatic](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegaragedoorcentre.co.uk%2FUserFiles%2FImage%2FHormann%2520Christmas%25202007%2520Promotion%2FPromatic_250.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) garage door openers, identical ones, both have a pair of built-in input connectors where anyone can use an external switch to trigger the garage doors to open/close.

My question is, how can I know whether it's safe for me to join the two minuses into one joint in order to use a wall switch like this to operate the two door openers independently?

[image]

According to the manual it uses a **24V DC** for the signal, however, it's **unclear** to me whether this connectors are "potential free", there is no clue whatsoever in the user's manual.

[image]

Comment: Measure the voltage difference between the commons with a DMM. If the voltage if high then it will be a problem. If the voltage difference is low, then use the DMM in Amps mode to connect them and see if there is a current flow. If the current flow is low or nonexistent then you should be OK.

Comment: Why can't you use a double pole switch?

Comment: If you measure between the grounds, do so during various operation modes -- at least while opening/closing.  Anyone know the symbol on the far right? ( D -> | )

Comment: D->I could be the obstacle detector, to prevent to door from crushing things.

Comment: it is, see figure 15 https://www.thegaragedoorcentre.co.uk/download/Garador%20GaraMatic%209.pdf

Comment: Thanks folks, great comments! Measuring the voltage difference / current with a DMM is a very good idea - thanks! Any ideas what voltage or current flow is "high"? And yes, a 2-pole switch would be ideal, but I already purchased the 1-pole and I didn't want it to go into the garbage.

Comment: More than a couple of volts is too high. More than 10 milliamps is too high.

Comment: The VDC difference of the two grounds connected is 0.0V. When in operation, it spikes to ~0.3V (the DMM is probably not fast enough to capture more). No current is measurable at all in mAMP / AMP mode. Everything sounds great so far. The only thing that makes me hesitate is that I finally got a response from Hormann's tech support and they said "You should not connect the two grounds of the 24V singal" - I don't know whether it can hurt the transformators long-term?